# Update table with data from other table without their indexes matching

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I need to update several rows with the data from a column of another table.

Say we have table A and B.
I need to update certain rows in A with data from B but I can only find the data from B by using data from A.

Basicly say a row from A has the ID "123" then I want to use this and search B for this ID and the get the unique ID of the row in B (which is not the same as As unique ID) and then change a column for this row in A with the unique ID of B.

I have over 2000 rows that needs to updated and since the value to set is dynamic I don't know how to setup the SQL query to adjust for this.

I have tested the following query:

```
update A
set B_id = (
    select B.id
    from B
    join A
    on B.BID = concat('FV', A.AID)
)
where AID in (*A bunch of values*);
```

B_id is a column in table A, B.id is a index and BID is a unique identifier, A has the same setup.

I did this and got the error message:
ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row

Comment: You don't need a join there. `where B.BID = concat('FV', A.AID)` should get it back to a scalar result. This is called a "correlated" subquery.

Comment: You were totally right @shawnt00 it worked like a charm when I removed the join. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you need this,

```
merge into A
using (select distinct B.id as id
    from B
    join A
    on B.BID = concat('FV', A.AID)) Tl
when matched then
update
set B_id = T1.id
where
communicationpointid in (*A bunch of values*);
```

More clarity on the requirement would be good